# Homomorphism from a subgroup to a group is injective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

I'm reading a proof and I don't quite understand one step of the proof.

We want to deduce that if G acts transitively on A then $ \bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma G_{a} \sigma^{-1} = 1$. (Where $G_{a}$ is the stabilizer of the group $G$.)

The proof goes something like this:

If G acts transitively on A, then we know from a prior exercise that the kernel of the action is $\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma G_{a} \sigma^{-1}$.

Here is the part I don't understand: Moreover, because $G \leq S_A$, the homomorphism $\iota : G \rightarrow S_A$ producing this action is injective, and thus has a trivial kernel. Thus $\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma G_{a} \sigma^{-1} = 1$.

I don't understand why a homomorphism from a subgroup to the group implies the homomorphism is injective.  Also, why does that imply that the kernel is trivial?

I know that the homomorphism is our permutation representation associated to the action.  I don't understand why $G$ being a subgroup of $S_A$ forces the homomorphism to be injective. For a mapping to be injective we have to have that whenever $x \neq y$, then $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

Please help.

Comment: It's a particular homomorphism, namely the inclusion. That seems to not be made sufficiently clear in the proof.

Comment: But why $G\leq S_A$? Is this an assumption?

Comment: Yes, sorry that this an assumption

Comment: Another proof of this was that by definition the kernel of the action is all the permutations in $S_A$ that fix every element of $A$.  The only permutation that does this is the identity perumtation.  So the kernel is 1.  But how do we know that the identity is the only permutation that does this?